# problema llenar datagridview c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, datagrid

hola tengo un problema al llenar el datagrid con la datos de mi BD, el datagrid es una grilla de horarios con los días de la semana, el problema es que solamente me llena una celda del datagrid por cada dia, es decir si yo tengo en la BD tres horarios cargados para un mismo día solo me muestra 1 (ni el primero ni el ultimo, muestra cualquiera de ese día).

> Aclaraciones sobre cosas testeadas al momento: La consulta a la BD devuelve todos los valores, en el condicional entra todas las veces lo cual es correcto pero no se porque no carga los valores en las celdas, es decir si tengo 10 valores cargados en mi BD y entra las 10 veces al condicional pero solo muestra algunos valores.

**Adjunto partes del código**

```
  if (query.Count() > 0)
        {
            int contador = 0;
            foreach (var item in query)
            {

                DateTime DiaTurno = new DateTime(myCal.GetYear(item.fecha_turno), myCal.GetMonth(item.fecha_turno), myCal.GetDayOfMonth(item.fecha_turno), new GregorianCalendar());

                int dia = (int)DiaTurno.DayOfWeek;

                string horario_turno = item.fecha_turno.ToString("HH:mm");


                for (int fila = 0; fila <= AgendaSemanal.Rows.Count - 1; fila++)
                {

                   /*EN ESTE CONDICIONAL ENTRA TODAS LAS VECES QUE DEBE PERO NO ME COMPLETA TODAS LAS CELDAS, SOLO ME COMPLETA 1 POR DIA*/
                        if (AgendaSemanal.Rows[fila].Cells[0].Value.ToString() == horario_turno)
                        {
                            AgendaSemanal.Rows[fila].Cells[dia+1].Value = item.nombre + " " + item.apellido;
                            AgendaSemanal.Rows[fila].Cells[dia + 1].Style.BackColor=System.Drawing.Color.Salmon;
                            AgendaSemanal.Rows[fila].Cells[dia + 1].Style.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;

         }
                        else
                             {

                             AgendaSemanal.Rows[fila].Cells[dia + 1].Value = "Libre";
                             AgendaSemanal.Rows[fila].Cells[dia + 1].Style.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Bisque;
                             AgendaSemanal.Rows[fila].Cells[dia + 1].Style.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
                            }


                }

            }



        }
```

Comment: Buenas @fer, creo que falta información en tu pregunta. No muestras como se llena la Grid, ni cómo debería ser el resultado y cómo es el resultado que te aparece ahora. Recuerda que cuanto mas concreta sea la pregunta mejores serán las respuestas que obtengas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que tu problema esta en la parte del else. 
Por cada ítem del query rellenas el grid y no compruebas si esta ocupada la fila.

Puedes probar este else

```html
 else
     {
     //compruebas que no tenga valor asignado la celda
     //aquí tu siempre escribes libre tenga valor o no
     if (this.AgendaSemanal.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value!=DBNull) //o con null o con lo que lo inicialices
       {
       AgendaSemanal.Rows[fila].Cells[dia + 1].Value = "Libre";
       AgendaSemanal.Rows[fila].Cells[dia + 1].Style.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Bisque;
       AgendaSemanal.Rows[fila].Cells[dia + 1].Style.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
       }
     }
```

Saludos

Comment: testeando el codigo me di cuenta que era el else, tenes razón gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Mi solución fue sacar el else que daba problemas y optar por llenar todo el datagrid con valores "Libre" para luego cargarle los datos de la BD, de todas formas destaco la solución de @Juanjo

```
//PRIMERO LLENO EL DATAGRID

 for (int fila = 0; fila <= AgendaSemanal.Rows.Count - 1; fila++)
        {   
            for (int col=1; col<AgendaSemanal.Columns.Count;col++)
            {
                AgendaSemanal.Rows[fila].Cells[col].Value = "Libre";
                AgendaSemanal.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = false;
                AgendaSemanal.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#cddfe1");
                AgendaSemanal.Rows[fila].Cells[col].Style.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.WhiteSmoke;
                AgendaSemanal.Rows[fila].Cells[0].Style.BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#cddfe1");
            }             


        }

//VERIFICO SI OBTUVE TURNOS REGISTRADOS EN LA BD
     if (query.Count() > 0)
        {
           //EN CASO DE QUE HAYA TURNOS RECORRO CADA UNO DE LOS TURNOS
            foreach (var item in query)
            {
                //ARMO EL DIA DEL TURNO SACADO DE LA BD
                DateTime DiaTurno = new DateTime(myCal.GetYear(item.fecha_turno), myCal.GetMonth(item.fecha_turno), myCal.GetDayOfMonth(item.fecha_turno), new GregorianCalendar());

                int dia = (int)DiaTurno.DayOfWeek;

                 // EL HORARIO SACADO DE LA BD LO CONVIERTO A STRING PARA QUE TENGA EL MISMO FORMATO QUE LAS FILAS DE HORARIOS DEL DATAGRID 
                 // ENTONCES AHI PUEDO COMPARAR ENTRE ELLOS
                string horario_turno = item.fecha_turno.ToString("HH:mm");
                //RECORRO TODAS LAS FILAS DEL DATA GRID, LAS COLUMNAS NO NECESITO RECORRERLAS YA QUE SU POSICION LAS DETERMINO CON EL NUMERO DE DIA DE LA SEMANA
                for (int fila = 0; fila <= AgendaSemanal.Rows.Count - 1; fila++)
                {

                  //HAGO COMPARACION DE HORARIOS ENTRE LA HORA DEL TURNO Y LA HORA DE CADA FILA DEL DATAGRID
                        if (AgendaSemanal.Rows[fila].Cells[0].Value.ToString() == horario_turno)
                        { //LLENO LA CELDA CON EL NOMBRE COMPLETO DEL PACIENTE
                            AgendaSemanal.Rows[fila].Cells[dia+1].Value = item.nombre + " " + item.apellido;

                         int resultado = DateTime.Compare(item.fecha_turno, DateTime.Now);//HAGO UNA COMPARACION ENTRE LA FECHA/HORA DEL TURNO Y LA FECHA/HORA ACTUAL
                        if (resultado <  0)// si el turno ya paso lo pongo de otro color
                        {
                            AgendaSemanal.Rows[fila].Cells[dia + 1].Style.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Salmon;

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (PrimeraAtencion(item.idpaciente) == 1)// si retorna 1 entonces ya fue atendido antes
                            {
                                AgendaSemanal.Rows[fila].Cells[dia + 1].Style.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGreen;
                                AgendaSemanal.Rows[fila].Cells[dia + 1].Style.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
                            }
                            //caso contrario es la primera vez que se atiende
                            else
                            {
                                AgendaSemanal.Rows[fila].Cells[dia + 1].Style.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
                                AgendaSemanal.Rows[fila].Cells[dia + 1].Style.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
                            }
                        }


                        }


                }

            }
```